# if there is a order to match when I use '|' in regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to get the table name from a sql (for example:`select name from user where id>5`).

I try to use regular expression,my pattern is `from\s+(.*)(\s*$|where)`

When the sql does not include 'where',it is ok. But if the sql include 'where', I will get 'user where id>5' as answer.

Because a sql may not have 'where', so I use `$`, but `(.*)(\s*$)` almost can match everything, I try to use this `from\s+(.*)(\s*where|$)`, I get the same wrong answer.

I wonder if there is a order to match when I use `|`?
how should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `.*` first eats everything, including the whereclause, and THEN it matches the `$`. The cause is the greedy `*`

You should append it with the lazy ?

Try `FROM\s+(.*?)(\s+WHERE|$)`